# C# IValueConverter Boolean a String

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, ivalueconverter

Hola amigos tengo una duda estoy aprendiendo a usar **IValueConverter** y necesito convertir un boolean a string, necesito que si mi bool es true me devuelva `"Carta en uso"` y si es false un string vacio ,esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
public class CardConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
           // ConnCard es mi modelo y UsingCard es mi booleano
            var con = (ConnCard)value;
            return con.UsingCard; // no si debo regresar aqui el string que quiero
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {           
        return value; // o aqui
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert va del VM a V... o sea que si al primero.. igual, probandolo no costaba mucho.. no ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usando operador ternario, lo hice de esta manera y siguiendo tu logica de como lo resolviste

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, ModelReponseUser culture)
    {
        var x = (bool)value;
        return x ? " " : "Carta en uso";
    }
```

otra manera, si quieres solo quieres evaluar `value` y que sea null, es de esta manera, porque veo que no estas usando `targetType`ni `parameter` nomas retornas el value

```
    return (bool)value ? " " : "Carta en uso";
```

aqui puedes ver varios ejemplos usando
[operadores ternarios](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien le sirve, quedo asi mi logica

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null )
        {
            //var con = (MopDTO)value;
            bool val = (bool)value;
            if (val != false)
            {
                return "Carta en uso";
            }
            else
            {
                return " ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return " ";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {           
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: porque no usar un operador ternario? si dices que cuanto es true debe devolver `Carta en uso` y cuanto es falso `" "`, quedaria mas o menos asi  `Carta en uso ?? " "`

Comment: @Daniel gustas poner un ejemplo para explicarte mejor?